# Jquery removing <p> tag from success fn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get response in my ajax success fn. My data variable gives me  `<p>hello</p>`.

How do I remove `<p>` and `</p>` from my data variable ?

I used `.remove()` but it is not working.

Comment: Please show us your attempt. It's easier to spot obvious mistakes if we can see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = '<p>hello</p>'
var text = $(data).text();
console.log(text);
```

Comment: :My data has <p>data<\/p>.Now if I use your code, <\/p> is not getting removed.

Comment: @user2261231 - What are you talking about? `<p>` *will* get removed because this code is getting the text in between `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

`.remove()` removes elements from the DOM, not from strings.

If you want to delete the `<p>` you can add the results to the DOM as hidden then remove the `<p>` and only then show it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [this example](http://jsbin.com/enijoq/1/edit). There will be no need to remove P tags.

```
var content = $(ajaxResponseString); //content = $("<p>Data</p>");
var html = content.html();
```

Advantages of this method:-

- Its more simple than using regular expressions.
- If your response comes as `<p id='paraId'> data </p>`. It will still run.
- Take this case `<p    > data </p>`, this approach will run fine while regex may/may not depending upon how clean your regex is.
- If your response changes tomorrow and you expect any other HTML tag too then you need to update your regex which can be quite complex to handle.

Comment: :How do I add var html to dom.Say to a div.

Comment: You have to just use selector to identify the div you are referring to and set its html as div.html(html);

Comment: :My data variable <p>hello<\/p>.

Comment: In your success handler, you just need to say var content=$(response.data); and then just say content.html() and store your data in some variable or do whatever you want. Just try it. its simple.

Comment: :my <\/p> is not getting removed.Can you try it out in jsfiddle.

Comment: Added link in my answer. Please refer to example. let me know if you are trying to do something different.

Comment: @user2261231 Generally I don't complain about this but you should at least check the time which answer came first and with how much detail..Its okay anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/b5bG8/

JS:-

```
var html = "<p>Some HTML</p>";
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;
var text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
alert(text);
```